# Fastest way to check if substring is at specific position of another string

Tags: javascript, string, performance

I have string (length 50-2000) and potential substring (length 2-8) which can only start at specific position (it may occur elsewhere but I don't care). I need to test large number of strings so speed is the key here. Is there faster way then:

```
var q = baseString.indexOf(searchString, assumedIndex) === assumedIndex;
```

or

```
var q = baseString.substr(assumedIndex, searchString.length) === searchString;
```

Comment: Do you have a performance issue?

Comment: My guess is the second is far faster because it has runtime `O(m)` where m is the length of the search string, whereas the first has `O(n)` where n is the length of the base string. And m is smaller than n. Although this is assuming a simple implementation of indexOf. Also these numbers aren't that large so big O notation isn't truely valid

Comment: @JosephYoung without a lot more details, your *guess* is exactly that, a guess, and it isn't much better than any other guess (would you the same if you knew there is 97% chance of the string matching immediately??)

Comment: Not at the moment, it's not in production yet. It's meant for 10k-500k checks and it takes second or so at worst (fast machine, syntetic data - might be optimized by browser in wrong way compared to real). But I can improve it's behavior if I add more similar indexOf/substr. Which will slow it down. So I'm looking for improving it.

Comment: @Amit Well, yes, but as I said I'm using big O notation, so this is assuming the worst case for the sake of argument. I wrote it in a comment because I didn't have an exact answer

Comment: [read this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/&ved=0ahUKEwiwvoW8lI_OAhXkB8AKHTHsDEsQFggbMAA&usg=AFQjCNHHgl2thOwkrzH4t0893kwl18FXFQ&sig2=sEMqiWH0mARBT2iIX28MqA)

Answer (score 0):

Keeping in mind what Amit said in the comments, I thought I might as well add an alternative that will (probably) be faster than at least the `substr` method:

```
var q = baseString.startsWith(searchString, assumedIndex);
```

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith):

> The `startsWith()` method determines whether a string begins with the
>   characters of another string, returning `true` or `false` as appropriate.

Small example:

```
> "Hello world!".startsWith("world!",6)
< true
```

The reason I argue it may be faster is because the polyfill (shown below) is directly what you implemented with `substr`, except that browser implementations will be implemented natively and probably without string copying. So it should be at least as fast as what you already suggested.

Polyfill:

```
if (!String.prototype.startsWith) {
    String.prototype.startsWith = function(searchString, position){
      position = position || 0;
      return this.substr(position, searchString.length) === searchString;
  };
}
```